# SQL Server Stored Procedure Sorting , Paging and Filtering on 2 million records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created a stored procedure that select some data from one table

table name ( t1  ) 
columns ( id , a , b )

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spGetData
    @DisplayLength INT,
    @DisplayStart INT,
    @SortCol INT,
    @SortDir NVARCHAR(10),
    @Search  NVARCHAR(255) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @FirstRec INT, @LastRec INT

    SET @FirstRec = @DisplayStart ;
    SET @LastRec = @DisplayStart + @DisplayLength;

    WITH CTE_Employees AS
    (
        SELECT
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY
                                   CASE WHEN (@SortCol = 0 AND @SortDir = 'asc') THEN id END asc,
                                   CASE WHEN (@SortCol = 0 AND @SortDir = 'desc') THEN id END desc,
                                   CASE WHEN (@SortCol = 1 AND @SortDir = 'asc') THEN a END asc,
                                   CASE WHEN (@SortCol = 1 AND @SortDir = 'desc') THEN a END desc,
                                   CASE WHEN (@SortCol = 2 AND @SortDir = 'asc') THEN b END asc,
                                   CASE WHEN (@SortCol = 2 AND @SortDir = 'desc') THEN b END desc) AS RowNumber, 
            COUNT(*) OVER () AS TotalCount, 
            id, a, b
        FROM
            t1
        WHERE
            (@Search IS NULL 
             OR id LIKE '%' + @Search + '%' 
             OR a LIKE '%' + @Search + '%' 
             OR b LIKE '%' + @Search + '%')
    )
    SELECT * 
    FROM CTE_Employees
    WHERE RowNumber > @FirstRec AND RowNumber <= @LastRec   
END
```

It takes about 20 seconds to run the following

```
spGetData 1000 ,0,0,'desc'
```

which is very slow. This procedure will be called later from an ASP.NET MVC project and the result will be displayed using jQuery datatables.

How can I improve the performance of it?

Comment: 5usec a record sounds very quick.

Comment: sorry ? what is 5usec

Comment: 5 microseconds.

Comment: it takes 20 seconds man

Comment: I meant 10 microseconds a record.  You have to read and filter each record one at a time.  So to get one record out of the database in under 10 microseconds is extremely fast.

Comment: but it will be slow when it used by jquery datatables, because with every action , it will execute the sp again

Comment: I don't think it can be run quicker.  See if removing the last Where changes the time.  It may be quicker to remove first row in c# after the results are returned.

Comment: I feel like the example is too abstract.  You are doing a CTE with Over clause in it where you are doing 3 wildcard searches.  I'm actually surprised it's only taking 20 seconds.  You should maybe look at the OFFSET/FETCH stuff and think about if you really need it to be a CTE or if you can do more of an SOA approach to get the lower level employees.


Also, if performance was a real issue I'd break this up into 6 queries and lose the case statement, then you can lose the over clause.

Answer (score 1):

First off, lose CTE. This is way too simple query for CTE.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spGetData
    @DisplayLength int,
    @DisplayStart int,
    @SortCol int,
    @SortDir nvarchar(10),
    @Search nvarchar(255) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        COUNT(*) OVER () AS TotalCount,
        id,
        a,
        b
    FROM t1
    WHERE 
        (@Search IS NULL OR 
         id LIKE '%'+@Search+'%' OR 
         a LIKE '%'+@Search+'%' OR 
         b LIKE '%'+@Search+'%')
    ORDER BY
        CASE 
            WHEN @SortDir = 'ASC' THEN 
                CASE @SortCol
                    WHEN 0 THEN id
                    WHEN 1 THEN a
                    WHEN 2 THEN b
                END 
            END desc,
        CASE 
            WHEN @SortDir = 'desc' THEN 
                CASE @SortCol
                    WHEN 0 THEN id
                    WHEN 1 THEN a
                    WHEN 2 THEN b
                END 
            END DESC
    OFFSET @DisplayStart ROWS
    FETCH NEXT @DisplayLength ROWS ONLY
END
```

This should be faster, but one more remark. LIKE searching within middle of string (`'%'+@Search+'%'`) can't use any indexing and will always be slow - especially on 2M rows and even worse - doing that on three different columns. It simply has to do a full table scan. 
Adding additional conditions (which are not LIKE) would improve performance.

Comment: would you be willing to expand on this -- formatting the result as JSON... question here:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/58700324/3772763